# How do I check an input .txt file for upper or lower case letters in Java or C++?

Tags: case, dna-sequence

I have found a lot of questions about converting letters from lower to upper case or vice versa, but I have a slightly different question:

I want to write a program that takes .txt files as input, reads them and detects all the positions in the text where the characters switch from upper case to lower case. For example, reading the input file:

> Test input.txt:
>   AJHFOJEOJkljklfjddejhjhoIOJOJFOJlkmlkloisjdo...

The program would tell me that the text switched from upper to lower case at positions 10 and 30.

I know, this makes no sense in regular English texts, since the text doesn't change very often from upper to lower case. However, my program is not supposed to read texts written in English but rather texts that contain DNA sequences in which all exons of a gene are written in upper case and all introns in lower case. To put it simple, my program is supposed to take DNA sequences as input (as .txt files) and then tell me all positions where an exon borders on an intron.

In the next step, the program is supposed to output and further process the last three upper case letters and the first six lower case letters from all the positions it detected in the first step. So, for the Test input.txt shown above, it would output:

> EOJkljklf  and  FOJlkmlkl

The purpose of the program is to find all so called 'splice donor sites' in any gene that I provide as a .txt file and then analyze them further.

(technical mumbo jumbo: a splice donor site is a sequence of nine bases at the exon/intron borders of an mRNA transcript [last three bases of the exon and first six bases of the following intron] where the U1 snRNA binds and initiates the splice process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are on a Linux environnement and that you are using the program on a command line terminal.

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int i, line_size;
  std::ifstream myfile;
  std::string token;

  // Check if user put an input file as argument
  if(argc < 2){
    std::cout << "Usage : ./parser filename" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  // Open file and check for errors
  myfile.open(argv[1]);
  if(!myfile){
    std::cout << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // For each line, put the line in variable token
  while(getline(myfile, token)){
    line_size = token.size();

    for(i=2; i < line_size - 4; ++i){
      // Go through the line and check for each character if it 
      // is an uppercase character and if the following one is
      // a lowercase character. If so, print it.
      if(std::isupper(token[i]) && std::islower(token[i+1])){
    std::cout << token.substr(i-2, 6) << std::endl;
      }
    }

  }

  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```